# Changing cleaned_data's output order

Tags: python-2.7, django-forms

Is there a way to change cleaned data's output order to return data by for ex. date?  As it seems default output order is alphabetic.
I need to pass cleaned_data's output as an argument to method and it's important to pass data in right order because method is using enumerate and adding sequence to each object received from cleaned_data.Classes example from:https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships.

FORM:

```
class GroupEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        group = super(GroupEditForm, self).save(commit=False)
        group.save()

        group.set_persons(self.cleaned_data['person'])

        if commit:
            group.save()
        return group
```

GROUP_MODEL'S_METHOD:

```
def set_persons(self, list_of_persons):
   for seq, person in enumerate(list_of_persons):
        Membership.objects.create(group=self, person=person,
            seq=seq+1)
```